# What's the difference between "come back" and "come on back"

Tags: phrase-meaning

In a video game I'm playing I've heard the phrase "**come on back to the base**" What is the difference between "come back" vs "come on back"

"**come on**"
3. verb To hurry up or move faster. To convey this meaning, the phrase is often used in the imperative.
*Come on, we're going to be late!* (source farlex dictionary of idioms)

Does it mean to hurry back into the base?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With most phrasal verbs, "on" can be inserted before the particle without changing the meaning. It adds a feeling a friendliness or "folksiness". It's associated with rural life, and is most common in the southern United States.

> come on down
> go on up
> step on through
> hand it on over

With some phrasal verbs, inserting "on" doesn't work as well, including those that end with "on" or "off". Most people would find these unnatural:

> take it on off
> turn it on on

Comment: Exactly, it's a little Southern.

Answer (score 1):

They both essentially mean the same thing, but "**come on back**" sounds a bit more like a friendly invitation, and "**come back**" sounds more like a regular imperative sentence (which would probably be more appropriate for an order, for example).

It's hard to judge without context, but if in your video game, a commander is ordering someone back to base, "come on back" sounds a bit too relaxed for that and "come back" might have been a better choice.

The impatient "**come on**" definition that you found is irrelevant to this.